# Lion 10.7.4 SSL bug?

Tags: ssl, osx-lion

When apache tests the ssl config it returns

> SSLCertificateFile: file '/private/etc/apache2/server.crt\xe2\x80\x9d' does not exist or is empty

it adds those weird "xe2" "x80" "x9d" references at the end of the .crt file whatever configuration the server uses ...and nothing seems to fix it

please...

Answer (score 0):

It's sounds like a non-ASCII double-quote (”, see "rdquo") was inserted by mistake.

If you can't see this character, try to delete that line and type it again, without the quote.

If you are using quotes, make sure that you are indeed using the ASCII-compatible quote (`"`) other forms of quotes.

Comment: I'm sorry Bruno where do you think that double-quote may have been inserted, please ?

Comment: In the configuration file, perhaps due to a copy/paste from somewhere else.